# Check Microsoft SQL Server Management studio is installed or not on machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How can find whether the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is installed on machine or not from the Registry Entry.

Comment: Are you looking for a script to do this? If not, then this is probably not the place to ask this kind of question. If so, then you what language (.net, powershell, etc.)?

Comment: If you are on Windows Vista or later, you can type `where ssms` into the console.

Comment: Thank you to both.i got the solution using .net.